# Find out which keystroke event is called

Tags: java

I'm making a class base on the java robot class.
The purpose of this is to be able to send thing like that :
"I like bananas, but not apple$ (however butter*)"

when looking at :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S

I can see several event, so I don't know wich one to choose.
for example "*" is called VK_ASTERISK or VK_MULTIPLY.

Therefor I'd like to display on the console the name of the keyevent triggered when I press a button.

is this possible?

(without making a huge switch testing all known event)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `getSource()` function should help you in this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()

Answer (score 0):

I made this from part found here and there, works fine

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();
    frame.add(nameTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        printIt("Pressed", keyEvent);
      }

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //printIt("Released", keyEvent);
      }

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //printIt("Typed", keyEvent);
      }

      private void printIt(String title, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        String keyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
        System.out.println(title + " : " + keyText + " / " + keyEvent.getKeyChar() + " code = " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
      }
    };
    nameTextField.addKeyListener(keyListener);

    frame.setSize(250, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

just run it, press a key and look at your eclipse console